# wheel package script points to local python path

Tags: python, python-wheel

I have a Python package with a script with the shebang `#!/usr/bin/env python`
. After I build a wheel of this package, I inspect the script inside the .whl and the new shebang is `#!/path/to/some/virtualenv/bin/python`. It's the path to a virtualenv which is not even the one active when I build the wheel.

```
> which python
#!/path/to/active/virtualenv/bin/python

> which wheel
#!/path/to/active/virtualenv/bin/wheel
```

This breaks distribution of my package. How can I fix this?

Comment: what is the output of echo $PATH? #!/usr/bin/env searches your current $PATH and uses the first python it finds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split process into 2 phases:

```
python setup.py build --executable '/usr/bin/env python' &&
python setup.py bdist_wheel [--universal]
```

`build` command creates `build/` subdirectory; when a `bdist_*` command (`bdist_egg` or `bdist_wheel`) detects the existence of the subdirectory it doesn't run `build` command but uses whatever `build` put in `build/`.

I use the approach in all my release scripts. Two examples: [Cheetah](https://github.com/CheetahTemplate3/cheetah3/blob/master/devscripts/release), [SQLObject](https://github.com/sqlobject/sqlobject/blob/master/devscripts/release).